# xcode 5 assign image inside storyboard

Tags: xcode

I haven't used xcode since version 4 and am getting back into it.

I am simply trying to add a static image inside my storyboard. I have dragged out a UiImageView, but cannot figure out where to assign the image to it. I remember I could do this in XCode 4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the image for an image view in the Attributes inspector:

[image: attributes inspector]

If you have images in your project, they'll show up in the popup.

Comment: Got it, it was collapsed!